# Stop requesting a script from loading in HTML-file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to stop a script from loading in HTML on my Wordpress website.
In my HTML file I can see these two scripts:

`<script type="0f1a6d7ca503db410c0d10c4-text/javascript" src='https://www.[-----------].se/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/assets/scripts/theme-my-login.min.js?ver=7.1.2' id='theme-my-login-js'></script>`

`<script type="0f1a6d7ca503db410c0d10c4-text/javascript" src='https://www. [-----------].se/wp-content/themes/guru/framework/js/public/jquery.smartresize.js?ver=5.5.2' id='jquery-smartresize-js'></script>`

In `public_html/wp-content/themes/guru/framework/register_public.php` I can **comment out** the second script and prevent it from loading to HTML by setting /* */ in the above php file:

```
/* wp_enqueue_script('jquery-smartresize', $template_uri.'/js/public/jquery.smartresize.js', array(), false, true); */
```

The first script comes from a plugin that I want to use on a certain page, so I do not want to deactivate the plugin. I will build a IF-statement in the php file to exclude/include the plugin script from loading into HTML based on page URL.

**My problem is that I cannot find the php file that loads the first script to HTML**, like I found for the second script. I do not find anything interesting or get to many hits when searching via ssh in public_html. Can I ad a filter? How would the code for the filter be? I guess it is better to prevent the wp_enqueue_script from excecuting than to have wp_enqueue_script and then add a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can dequeue the scripts where they're not needed

```php
function SO_21097900() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-my-login' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-smartresize' );
}

if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) &&
 strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'the/page/that/uses/the/scripts' ) === false ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scrips', 'SO_21097900', 100 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I only used

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) &&
strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'the/page/that/uses/the/scripts' ) === false ) 
{wp_dequeue_script( 'theme-my-login' );
}
```

I did not call on the function SO_21097900...that did not work...I do not know where to put the function. If I put the function in the same php file then my website goes down.